# How can I sum these Javascript values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I have the following array of objects. Each object has a pair of objects within it for two people. It's holding scores, e.g. game 1 for Bob has 10 points, then game 2, 9 points etc.

```
var arr = [{
  "bob": {
    "1": "10",
    "2": "9",
    "3": "9",
    "4": "10",
    "5": "9",
    "6": "7",
    "7": "10",
    "8": "10",
    "9": "10",
    "10": "9",
    "11": "10",
    "12": "8"
  },
  "max": {
    "1": "9",
    "2": "10",
    "3": "10",
    "4": "8",
    "5": "10",
    "6": "10",
    "7": "8",
    "8": "9",
    "9": "9",
    "10": "10",
    "11": "9",
    "12": "10"
  }
},

{
  "bob": {
    "1": "10",
    "2": "9",
    "3": "9",
    "4": "10",
    "5": "9",
    "6": "7",
    "7": "10",
    "8": "10",
    "9": "10",
    "10": "9",
    "11": "10",
    "12": "8"
  },
  "max": {
    "1": "9",
    "2": "10",
    "3": "10",
    "4": "8",
    "5": "10",
    "6": "10",
    "7": "8",
    "8": "9",
    "9": "9",
    "10": "10",
    "11": "9",
    "12": "10"
  }
},
{
  "bob": {
    "1": "10",
    "2": "9",
    "3": "9",
    "4": "10",
    "5": "9",
    "6": "7",
    "7": "10",
    "8": "10",
    "9": "10",
    "10": "9",
    "11": "10",
    "12": "8"
  },
  "max": {
    "1": "9",
    "2": "10",
    "3": "10",
    "4": "8",
    "5": "10",
    "6": "10",
    "7": "8",
    "8": "9",
    "9": "9",
    "10": "10",
    "11": "9",
    "12": "10"
  }
}
]
```

How can I loop through each pair of objects (bob & max) and create an average out all of it? I find looping within loops really confusing... I'm struggling how to write the question.

The end goal is to have one pair of objects of which the values would be averaged from all of the previous ones in the array. E.G for each person, I need to add up each up the scores (scores 1 - 12) and then create a final average score. I hope this makes sense? In terms of what I have tried, I've tried to manipulate a lot of other SO answers to fit my needs but I kept running into error after error and thus isn't worth posting with this...

```
 // Final averaged scores for each person based on the total data available
[{
  "bob": {
    "1": "10",
    "2": "9",
    "3": "9",
    "4": "10",
    "5": "9",
    "6": "7",
    "7": "10",
    "8": "10",
    "9": "10",
    "10": "9",
    "11": "10",
    "12": "8"
  },
  "max": {
    "1": "9",
    "2": "10",
    "3": "10",
    "4": "8",
    "5": "10",
    "6": "10",
    "7": "8",
    "8": "9",
    "9": "9",
    "10": "10",
    "11": "9",
    "12": "10"
  }
}]
```

Comment: Why aren't you using arrays if you're going to have numerical keys?

Comment: Because it serves other purposes elsewhere in the script unrelated to this issue right here.

Comment: I am not clear on your goal. Do you want an average of all Bob's "1", "2", etc scores (and the same for Max)?

Comment: Yeah so... take all of bobs scores in each object and create an average object of scores for example

Comment: Why do you store scores as strings? This data structure is really inefficient.

Comment: Because that's how I *receive* the data. I could change it I suppose but do I **need** to?

Comment: I don't see any difference in the desired output compared to the first pair of objects in the input. Also you write that want to add up each of the scores (1 - 12), but I still see them separate in the output. Can you give a more telling example where we can see how you have calculated the output?

Comment: The desired output example doesn't actually contain correctly calculated averages, I just copied and paste it in. I did that in hope that it made more sense with a bit more of a visual clue to help you guys see my goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a single loop approach for calculating the wanted avarage. This proposal feature ES5.

Variables:

- `r`: temporary result in [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce),
- `o`: object, an item of the array,
- `a`: the reference to he calling array, needed for the length,
- `k`, `l`: keys of the nested object.

Patterns:

- `||`: [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) as default operator.

```js
var array = [{ bob: { 1: "10", 2: "9", 3: "9", 4: "10", 5: "9", 6: "7", 7: "10", 8: "10", 9: "10", 10: "9", 11: "10", 12: "8" }, max: { 1: "9", 2: "10", 3: "10", 4: "8", 5: "10", 6: "10", 7: "8", 8: "9", 9: "9", 10: "10", 11: "9", 12: "10" } }, { bob: { 1: "10", 2: "9", 3: "9", 4: "10", 5: "9", 6: "7", 7: "10", 8: "10", 9: "10", 10: "9", 11: "10", 12: "8" }, max: { 1: "9", 2: "10", 3: "10", 4: "8", 5: "10", 6: "10", 7: "8", 8: "9", 9: "9", 10: "10", 11: "9", 12: "10" } }, { bob: { 1: "10", 2: "9", 3: "9", 4: "10", 5: "9", 6: "7", 7: "10", 8: "10", 9: "10", 10: "9", 11: "10", 12: "8" }, max: { 1: "9", 2: "10", 3: "10", 4: "8", 5: "10", 6: "10", 7: "8", 8: "9", 9: "9", 10: "10", 11: "9", 12: "10" } }],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, o, _, a) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            r[k] = r[k] || {};
            Object.keys(o[k]).forEach(function (l) {
                r[k][l] = (r[k][l] || 0) + o[k][l] / a.length;
            });
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: that is pretty awesome, but when explaining, try not to use single-letter-params. They make it a bit harder to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.reduce(function(res, obj, index, array) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(player) {
        res[player] = res[player] || {};
        Object.keys(obj[player]).forEach(function(game) {
            res[player][game] = res[player][game] || 0;
            res[player][game] += parseFloat(obj[player][game] / array.length);
        });
    });
    return res;
}, {});
```

Comment: It's correct because dividing the sum of multiple numbers is the same as summing these numbers divided.
(a + b + c) / d = (a / d) + (b / d) + (c / d)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `array.map` and `array.reduce` to return a sum of the scores.

```js
console.clear();

var games = [
  {
    "bob": { "1": "10", "2": "9", "3": "9", "4": "10" },
    "max": { "1": "9", "2": "10", "3": "10", "4": "8" }
  },
  {
    "bob": { "1": "10", "2": "9", "3": "9", "4": "10" },
    "max": { "1": "9", "2": "10", "3": "10", "4": "8" }
  },
  {
    "bob": { "1": "10", "2": "9", "3": "9", "4": "10" },
    "max": { "1": "9", "2": "10", "3": "10", "4": "8" }
  }
];

let scores = {};
games.forEach( game => {
  Object.keys(game).forEach( player => {
    scores[player] = scores[player] || {};
    Object.keys(game[player]).forEach(gameNumber => {
      scores[player][gameNumber] = scores[player][gameNumber] || [];
      scores[player][gameNumber].push(parseInt(game[player][gameNumber]));
    });
  });
});

Object.keys(scores).forEach( player => {
  Object.keys(scores[player]).forEach(game => {
    let total = scores[player][game].reduce((a, b) => { return a+b; });
    let length = scores[player][game].length;
    
    scores[player][game] = total / length;
  });
});

console.info( scores );
```

Comment: Is this ES5 syntax? Honestly, I have no idea what this is.

Comment: looks like i misunderstood your question, let me rework this a bit :-D

Comment: @ProEvilz What is it you don't understand?

Comment: I guess my brain just can't generally handle recursion/loops within loops. What does || mean in this context?

Comment: @ProEvilz `if (typeof scores[player] === 'undefined') { scores[player] = {}; } else { scores[player] = scores[player]; }`

It means, if the first value is `falsey`, take the second value. Check out the answers by @NinaScholz and @Ammar.

Answer (score 0):

I used basic loops for this :

```
var gameCount = arr.length;

var outPutArr = {"bob":{},"max":{}};

// Initialize the output array
for(var i=1;i<=Object.keys(arr[0].bob).length;i++)
{
    outPutArr["bob"][i+""] = "0";
    outPutArr["max"][i+""] = "0";
}

// Loop through all games and add score of bob and max
arr.forEach(function(item){
    for(var i=1;i<=Object.keys(arr[0].bob).length;i++)
    {
        outPutArr["bob"][i+""] = (parseInt(item["bob"][i+""]) + parseInt(outPutArr["bob"][i+""]))+"";
        outPutArr["max"][i+""] = (parseInt(item["max"][i+""]) + parseInt(outPutArr["max"][i+""]))+"";
    }
});

for(var i=1;i<=Object.keys(arr[0].bob).length;i++)
{
    outPutArr["bob"][i+""] = (parseInt(outPutArr["bob"] [i+""])/gameCount)+"";
    outPutArr["max"][i+""] = (parseInt(outPutArr["max"] [i+""])/gameCount)+"";
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(outPutArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this be what you wanted? 
It sums for however users you have scores from how much games you have (as long as it's not 100+ per single object) and stores results in summs object

You can observe results in console from this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2m8gtcgm/)

```
var arr = [{
  "bob": {
    "1": "10",
    "2": "9",
    "3": "9",
    "4": "10",
    "5": "9",
    "6": "7",
    "7": "10",
    "8": "10",
    "9": "10",
    "10": "9",
    "11": "10",
    "12": "8"
  },
  "max": {
    "1": "9",
    "2": "10",
    "3": "10",
    "4": "8",
    "5": "10",
    "6": "10",
    "7": "8",
    "8": "9",
    "9": "9",
    "10": "10",
    "11": "9",
    "12": "10"
  }
},

{
  "bob": {
    "1": "10",
    "2": "9",
    "3": "9",
    "4": "10",
    "5": "9",
    "6": "7",
    "7": "10",
    "8": "10",
    "9": "10",
    "10": "9",
    "11": "10",
    "12": "8"
  },
  "max": {
    "1": "9",
    "2": "10",
    "3": "10",
    "4": "8",
    "5": "10",
    "6": "10",
    "7": "8",
    "8": "9",
    "9": "9",
    "10": "10",
    "11": "9",
    "12": "10"
  }
},
{
  "bob": {
    "1": "10",
    "2": "9",
    "3": "9",
    "4": "10",
    "5": "9",
    "6": "7",
    "7": "10",
    "8": "10",
    "9": "10",
    "10": "9",
    "11": "10",
    "12": "8"
  },
  "max": {
    "1": "9",
    "2": "10",
    "3": "10",
    "4": "8",
    "5": "10",
    "6": "10",
    "7": "8",
    "8": "9",
    "9": "9",
    "10": "10",
    "11": "9",
    "12": "10"
  }
}
]

var summs = {};

arr.forEach(function(users, ind, arr){
    for (var user in users) {
    if (users.hasOwnProperty(user)) {
      if (!summs.hasOwnProperty(user)) summs[user] = 0;
      console.log(users[user]);
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            if (users[user].hasOwnProperty(i+'')){
                summs[user] += parseInt(users[user][i]);
            }
      }
    }
  } 
});
console.log(summs);
```